# How to fix the MT5210 error when linking the project in monotouch

Tags: hyperlink, xamarin.ios

when I binding the obj-C static library,I have encountered an error.

Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _ASN1_INTEGER_get. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. (MT5210)

I have added the linkflags:   but problem still exists.

(pls find the attacment - link to download the project source code: http://web.chinamail.com.cn/coremail/viewDownloadFile.jsp?key=1U31SsvkjDKKh8jW-sKpSejdo9FpT7FAantnwBILzVvton2LzVFmT9EAfnJL3ZElon2kz48ZwbGpS4APTuYBzVFmT9EAfnJMfeYpzsFP-sKqTs0mTbk8Ss2maUrUUUUjjnCgTuDn0ka6r4rtFy3ZFWrXFWxGFcF6hVqUfZk1Tsvk1q3Ur7jAUn5U-7jjU08U27jnU87Ur7jeU83U3DjnU8kUwUjXUnfU77jjUntUh70mUiEH4GA=&code=9zj2jqjt )

Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. (MT5210)

Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _X509_STORE_CTX_get_ex_data. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. (MT5210)

Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _sk_num. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. (MT5210)

"_SSL_CTX_free", referenced from:
      _init_openssl in libEaseMobClientSDKLite.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
      _reset_ssl_sock_state in libEaseMobClientSDKLite.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
      _create_ssl in libEaseMobClientSDKLite.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)
  "_SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations", referenced from:
      _create_ssl in libEaseMobClientSDKLite.a(ssl_sock_ossl.o)

I have added the linkflags:

[assembly: LinkWith ("libEaseMobClientSDKLite.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s | LinkTarget.Simulator, ForceLoad = true,
    Frameworks="SystemConfiguration QuartzCore OpenGLES Security CoreText ImageIO MapKit CoreLocation MobileCoreServices AddressBook CFNetwork UIKit Foundation Social CoreGraphics",
    LinkerFlags = "-lz -lxml2 -liconv -lresolv -lstdc++"
)]

the following screen-snapshot is the ObjC project which can build sucessfully by XCode.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

Those symbols looks like they come from OpenSSL (libssl) and this is not something that is part of the `[LinkWith]` attribute you showed. It's also not something you can add to the `LinkerFlags=` list of *dynamic* libraries you can link with.

**Solution**

- You are likely missing another static `.a` library for your project; *or*
- `libEaseMobClientSDKLite.a` you're using is mis-compiled (and would normally include the openssl object files).

If you have an ObjC sample for *EaseMobClientSDKLite* then you can look at Xcode build logs (the link step) to see what's (and how) openssl is being referenced in the build.

Comment: I have upload the screen-snapshot above , which is the ObjC project that can be build sucessfully by XCode.